# Redirect to description page from Card component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect

Appreciate your kind help!

**What I'm trying to achieve is that on click of cardlist component it has to open respective product detail page just like e-commerce website.**
I have created :

> CardList component, card component, data(where it contain array of
> object) and singleCardComponent(i.e the description page component)
> **I think I had made a mistake in cardList component.**

I have got stuck on the logic how i will redirect to respective product page.

```
    //--------------------card component--------------------
class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='col-md-3 col-10 mx-auto mb-4'>
                <div className="card">
                    <img src={this.props.imgsrc} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">Rs {this.props.price}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{this.props.title}</p>
                        <p className='card-date d-flex justify-content-end'>Oct 29</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

//--------------------cardlist component--------------------
class CardList extends Component {
    show_component = (i) => {
        Data.map((v) => {
            return <SingleCardComp
                key={i}
                imgsrc={v.imgsrc}
                price={v.price}
                title={v.title}
                seller={v.seller_desc}
                desc={v.description}
                loc={v.location}
            />
        })

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
                {
                    Data.map((val, i) => {
                        return <button onClick={()=>this.show_component(i)}>
                            <Card
                                key={i}
                                imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                                price={val.price}
                                title={val.title}
                            />
                        </button>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
//--------------------Data--------------------
const Data = [
    {
        imgsrc: image0,
        title: "Samsung A50",
        price: 35500,
        seller_desc: 'Bilal',
        description: "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit",
        location:'Kansas'
    }
];

//--------------------SingleCardComp--------------------
class SingleCardComp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={this.props.imgsrc} alt="..." />
                <h5>Rs {this.props.price}</h5>
                <p >{this.props.title}</p>
                <h1>
                    Description:{this.props.desc}
                </h1>
                <h1>
                    Seller Details:{this.props.seller}
                </h1>
                <h1>
                    Posted in:{this.props.loc}
                </h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Here is the image of card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxJLH.png)

Answer (score 0):

The show_component method seems the problem here,

What is the `Data` means in the show_component method? Is that the same array used in `CardList->render` method? If that is the case what you need to do is update your show_component method like this,

```
 show_component = (i) => {
    Data.map((v, index) => {
        if(index === i) {
            return <SingleCardComp
            key={i}
            imgsrc={v.imgsrc}
            price={v.price}
            title={v.title}
            seller={v.seller_desc}
            desc={v.description}
            loc={v.location}
        />
        }
    })

}
```

This is the solution with minimum change. However, the better solution would be to pass the card data in the show_component method as parameter. Like this,

```
state = {
    selectedItem: null,
    showSingleCardComp: false,
    selectedItemIndex: 0,
}

show_component = (v, i) => {
    this.setState({selectedItem: v, showSingleCardComp: true, selectedItemIndex: i});
}
```

And call the show_component method like this,

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='row'>
            {
                Data.map((val, i) => {
                    return <button onClick={()=>this.show_component(val, i)}>
                        <Card
                            key={i}
                            imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                            price={val.price}
                            title={val.title}
                        />
                    </button>
                })
            }
            {this.state.showSingleCardComp && (
            <SingleCardComp
                key={this.state.selectedItemIndex}
                imgsrc={this.state.selectedItem.imgsrc}
                price={this.state.selectedItem.price}
                title={this.state.selectedItem.title}
                seller={this.state.selectedItem.seller_desc}
                desc={this.state.selectedItem.description}
                loc={this.state.selectedItem.location}
             />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Well, I received that particular value and index in the parameters of show_component() but still it didn't redirect me to the **SingleCardComp.jsx**. What cause it to do so??

Comment: You can not redirect to a component. You have to set the clicked product data in the state and a flag variable. Then depending on the flag variable you can render the SingleCardComp using the product data in state. I am updating the code according to your requirement.

Comment: Sorry brother for disturbing, my doubts aren't clear yet. 
I want same functionality as this website have, when we click on products(i.e ads) it take us to detail page
[https://www.olx.com.pk/]
_How to make like this? any guide or amendment on the above code._
**Appreciate your kind help!**

Comment: Sorry, this is a large topic for discussing here. You need to do some reading. Here is a link to get you started. http://tszekely.github.io/react-learning-module/step-06